# Is there a way to set and push at the same time in a Redux action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js, saga

```
case 'MODIFY_NODES': {

    if (action.payload.nodes) {
        for (const node of action.payload.nodes) {
            const setNodes = action.payload.nodes.filter(n => state.findIndex((item) => item.get('id') == n.id) )
            const pushNodes = action.payload.nodes.filter(n => state.findIndex((item) => item.get('id') != n.id) )
            if (setNodes.length > 0) {
                return state.set(index, fromJS(node, toImmutableFunction)) 
            }
            if (pushNodes.length > 0) {
                return state.push(fromJS(pushNodes, toImmutableFunction))
            }
            
        }
    }
    return state

}
```

I need to call set and push on a set of elements, but I can't do both since I need to return something once. Is there a hack around this? I am trying to figure out what can be done, but I can't think of anything. I am thinking I need to call a saga function and then make two different calls after splitting the payload there. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that this is generally a very old style of Redux and the official recommendation would be not to use `immutablejs` any more since around 2019 - please read [Why Redux Toolkit is how to write Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today).

It would be probably something along these lines:

```js
const setNodes = action.payload.nodes.filter(n => state.findIndex((item) => item.get('id') == n.id) )
const pushNodes = action.payload.nodes.filter(n => state.findIndex((item) => item.get('id') != n.id) )

let intermediateState = state;
for (const node of setNodes) {
  intermediateState = intermediateState.set(index, fromJS(node, toImmutableFunction)) 
}
for (const node of pushNodes) {
  intermediateState = intermediateState.push(fromJS(pushNodes, toImmutableFunction))
}
return intermediateState
```